# Have you ever used parabolic reflectors for field recording?

Tags: field-recording, techniques, gear, microphone

I know that here is an dust-covered Sony reflector somewhere in the warehouse. It got lost when headquarters moved two years ago. I never used it so I´ve asked my boss to look for it in order to try it out outdoors. I will use with an MKE-2 (lavalier omni) and with my MKH-406 (cardioid). Does anyone have experience with this kind of reflectors?

[Sony Parabolic reflector http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_44dvHZ3XXO4/S68sWRaroCI/AAAAAAAAE7M/93wbld7j2uQ/s400/PBR-330.jpg](http://surround2011.blogspot.com/2010/03/parabolic-reflector-sony-pbr-330.html)

Comment: Nice picture Iain, is it cool or what?

Answer (score 4):

I've never used one but I know their frequency response is proportional to the size of the dish...

http://www.coe.montana.edu/ee/rmaher/publications/maher_aac_0805.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Useful link. I saw it just once some years ago and I remember it quite small. Anyway, if we can find it I´ll bring it back to life. 

Answer (score 2):

Hey, I know this is an old thread, but I just had my first experience with a parabolic dish mic. They're tricky to aim and use, but if the dish is transparent, that helps a lot. As Tim mentioned, the size of the dish determines its low-end characteristics...that's why they're usually awesome for birdsong, but if you need fat low-end, you'll be very disappointed. I used a 2' wide dish - kinda big! - and it seemed decent through the midtones and had very articulate high frequencies.

If you don't put this on a tripod, your life will suck. I strongly recommend a ball head instead of a pan-tilt head; way faster to aim it, lock it, and stop futzing.